# How to make electron browser fulle screen size?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm having trouble making and electron browser the full screen width, but to maintain the minimize/maximize buttons. Using the following does what I want, but I loose my toggle buttons by doing so. Is there an alternative method I can use?

```
window.setFullScreen(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [window.maximize()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-maximize)

To do it on startup, try this:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
win.maximize()
win.show()
```

## Notes

- Checkout out [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7076) for more information.
- Also the [BrowserWindow API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) has even more information